# Ubuntu Server installation freezes during installation

Tags: server, startup

I have an old Gateway Tower that was running Windows XP, but after XP stopped working on me, I decided to make it into a server, and install Ubuntu Server.

BUT, it keeps freezing on me.

During this setup, this happened once to me while I was Selecting the keyboard layout, but now, it happened after I partioned the disk. (Right now it is at 34% of "Installing the Base System") Last time, I just turned the computer off, and it worked again, but I remember hearing someone say that if you turn off your computer while it is partioning the disk, that it could corrupt your files.

Is it safe to turn off, and is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing, then yes there's a chance that it will corrupt the files... but to be fair, if you cut it off during the installation you're going to have to install again and, if you wanted to be safe, remake the partition tables so that's not really a concern (at least not to me.)

You said Windows XP stopped working... What went wrong? If it was hardware related the same problems could be affecting Ubuntu and causing it to lock up as well.

Since you're new here, you can comment on my post to reply to me. Also, if this is a helpful reply you can click the up arrow next to it.

Comment: When I had Windows XP, I kept getting errors that file was missing. I think it was something like win.sys, but I'm not sure. It asked me to put in my install disks, which I didn't have, so I tried to install Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, I think I just found my problem. When I restarted my computer, it froze at the Gateway startup screen, and started making a clicking noise. (Ka-No Ka-No Ka-No Ka-No Ka-No would be my best description of it.) I remembered that this could mean a failing hard drive, so I took a minite to search google. When I found nothing, and returned to the computer, the clicking had stopped and it was showing a message: The Hard Drive could not be found. Consult the troubleshooting manual. When I restarted the computer, I got a similar message: A problem with the hard drive has been detected.(Cont. below)

Comment: (Sorry, ran out of words) Anyway, now when I startup my computer, I either get the clicking and first message, or no clicking and second message. So I think I see why Ubuntu isn't working.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like HDD failure. If you have a spare one on hand, try swapping it out. If not, luckily they're relatively inexpensive.